# Can we install Cloudwatch Log agent on Windows EC2 instance? AWS documentation doesn't talk about windows instances at all

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Has anyone has installed cloudwatch agent on windows servers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I found the answer to my question

This is the documentation:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/07/10/introducing-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/

Comment: But it still doesn't point to the link to  CloudWatch logs agent for windows (it simply says that there IS one available)